# Implementing a Copy-Constructor with Serializeable class

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a Class `MyClass` which implements is Serializeable to XML, I use this to simply persist the data.

Now I need to implement a Copy-Constructor and every Field that needs to be copied is also beeing serialized, so it'd be the most easy way to achieve my solution.

This is what i've tried so far

```
    static public MyClass Clone(MyClass MyClass)
    {
        MyClass clone;
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), _xmlAttributeOverrides);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(ms, MyClass);
            clone = (MyClass)ser.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

It using the serialisation Funcions of the `XmlSerializer` does work when im using a `FileStream` but in this case I get an `InvalidOperationException` in the `Deserialize(Stream)`-Method.

Stack trace

```
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
   bei Namespace.MyClass.Clone(MyClass myClass)
```

I've never been using a MemoryStream before, but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dsh84875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) microsoft tells me I can use this Stream with serialisation.

Tell me what I'm not seeing :)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `XmlSerializer` instead of creating copying the fields?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The Structure is pretty deep and the stuff that needs to be copied is exact the same that's beeing serialized. There's enough performance, so its a quite achievable short solution.

Comment: I'm assuming that `BinaryFormatter` would be faster. Look into that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thanks I'll have a look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before

```
clone = (MyClass)ser.Deserialize(ms);
```

add:

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

You could also implement a Cloning functionality so that you don't need to serialize/deserialize an xml to some stream.

Comment: Thanks this works. I know there are several possibilities for doing this. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) I've read a lot about this.